# How do I use an advice to change the definition of goto-char within a function?

Tags: advice

Suppose a third-party plugin contains the following function:

```lisp
(defun example-function ()
  (interactive)
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max))
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max))
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max)))
```

The function uses `goto-char` in various places in its body.

I want to change the behavior of the function such that every time it calls `(goto-char (point-max))`, it will also call `(recenter -1)`. To that end, I added this advice to redefine the calls to `goto-char`:

```lisp
(advice-add 'example-function
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (cl-labels ((goto-char (pos)
                            (goto-char pos)
                            (recenter -1)))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```

However, the `cl-labels` appears to have no effect; `goto-char` still retains its old behavior inside `example-function`. What is wrong with the advice?

(Emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2)

Comment: You can't change the behavior of `goto-char` just inside `example-function` using an advice. You have two options: rewrite `example-function` to call `recenter` after every `goto-char`; or add an `:after` advice to `goto-char` which calls `recenter`. In the latter case, the advised `goto-char` will be called every time, not just from inside `example-function`.

Answer (score 3):

(Caveat: All from memory; I might have some of this wrong.)

WRT your code:

```el
(lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (cl-labels ((goto-char (pos)
                            (goto-char pos)
                            (recenter -1)))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```

You never call `goto-char` in the body of that `cl-labels` form, so your override wouldn't be used.

It's the `orig-fun` definition which would be calling `goto-char`, but *that* code is not within the lexical scope of the `cl-labels` code.

Generally, using `cl-letf` with `(symbol-function 'foo)` as the PLACE allows dynamically-scoped overrides (i.e. seen by other functions as well as the immediate code), but even then I think this kind of override could only work in uncompiled code, as `goto-char` has its own byte-code op, meaning that calls to it are compiled away to just that op code when it's byte-compiled (which also inhibits writing advice for `goto-char` itself).

Comment: n.b. Chris Wellons wrote a good article about byte code vs advice: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/01/22/

Comment: +1. Two good points in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is wrong with your code, but it seems like it should not work because you are recursively calling goto-char inside the definition. You would have to redefine the goto-char function (which is in the C code I think). I think you need to advise the goto-char function temporarily like this:

```
(defun example-function ()
  (interactive)
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max))
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max))
  ;; ... do many things ...
  (goto-char (point-max)))


(defun modified-goto-char (orig-fun &rest args)
  (apply orig-fun args)
  (recenter -1))


(advice-add 'example-function
            :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              (advice-add 'goto-char :around #'modified-goto-char)
              (apply orig-fun args)
              (advice-remove 'goto-char #'modified-goto-char)))
```